# how to make unstretched camera view in limited height? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am viewing the camera within a restricted height area and it automatically adjusts the aspect ratio. I want to make the width equal to the device width but the view should not be distorted, I don't want it to be a stretched view. How can I do?

Cropping is fine, all I want is to make the width equal to the screen width and the unstretched image.

I use "camera" plugin.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: CameraPreview(_controller),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 230,
            child: ///some elements here, this area fix
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried many resizing solutions but they all resulted in a stretched view.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code where you want to show your camera.

Modify values according to your requirement.

```
return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: ClipRect(
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: 1 / _cameraController?.value?.aspectRatio ?? 1,
            child: Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                child: CameraPreview(_cameraController),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Sanket Patel's suggestion, I got what I wanted as follows.

```
ClipRect(
                  child: Transform.scale(
                    scale: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: Center(
                      child: CameraPreview(_controller),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```